# How to give different href on single image use map and coords?

Tags: html, css, dictionary

[image]

How to give different a href all menu
for eg;
1)Data handling 
2)Research

Comment: you can also use `position:absolute` and place `<a>` tags where you want http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/e9o6my7e/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use image mapping. Below links will help you to do this.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

http://www.image-maps.com/